# nodeJS Crawler : unable to get the tagname associated with search word

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I have created a crawler in NodeJS

I have a website : "http://www.google.com"  for which I have written the crawler

**Technology** used is nodeJS, cheerio

**Sample example of what I have achieved  :**

For example , lets search google.com. there is a button called "google search".

Let us search for the text "google search". Today my crawler can find the word in the page and say it has found it.

Today it shows : text " google search" found on google.com

**What I need the result to be :**

What it needs to do is in addition to finding text, also tell me the tag name , that in this case is a *button*

Needed output is : text "google search" found on google.com of *"TAGNAME: BUTTON"*

I tried using indexOf, but it isn't working. Please suggest how to do ?

Here is the code
!!!

```js
index.js
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var URL = require('url-parse');

var START_URL = "https://www.mytravelexp.com/";
var SEARCH_WORD ="Pack your travel essentials";
var MAX_PAGES_TO_VISIT = 20;

var pagesVisited = {};
var numPagesVisited = 0;
var pagesToVisit = [];
var url = new URL(START_URL);
var baseUrl = url.protocol + "//" + url.hostname;

pagesToVisit.push(START_URL);
crawl();

function crawl() {
  if(numPagesVisited >= MAX_PAGES_TO_VISIT) {
    console.log("Reached max limit of number of pages to visit.");
    return;
    
  }
  var nextPage = pagesToVisit.pop();
  if (nextPage in pagesVisited) {
    // We've already visited this page, so repeat the crawl
    crawl();
  } else {
    // New page we haven't visited
    visitPage(nextPage, crawl);
  }
}

function visitPage(url, callback) {
  // Add page to our set
  pagesVisited[url] = true;
  numPagesVisited++;

  // Make the request

  request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    console.log("***************************")
    console.log(" Visiting page: " +  url + '\n');
     if(response.statusCode !== 200) {
       callback();
       return;
     }
     // Parse the document body
     var $ = cheerio.load(body);
     var isWordFound = searchForWord($, SEARCH_WORD);
     if(isWordFound) {
       console.log(' ' + SEARCH_WORD + ' found at page ' + url);
       collectInternalLinks($);
       callback();
     } else {
       collectInternalLinks($);
       // In this short program, our callback is just calling crawl()
       callback();
     }
  });
}

function searchForWord($, word) {
  var bodyText = $('html > body').html().toLowerCase();
  return(bodyText.includes(word.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
}

function collectInternalLinks($) {
    var relativeLinks = $("a[href^='/']");
    relativeLinks.each(function() {
        pagesToVisit.push(baseUrl + $(this).attr('href'));
    });
    
    var absoluteLinks = $("a[href^='http']");
    absoluteLinks.each(function() {
        pagesToVisit.push($(this).attr('href'));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( $('123')[0].name === 'button' ){
    console.log($('button').contents().first().text());
    console.log( $('123').attr('name') );
}
```